# On multivariate polynomials and their real roots

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, roots

We know that a real polynomial in one variable admits an even number of real roots when its degree is even and an odd number of roots when its degree is odd.

How does that extend to real multivariate polynomials ? What if I have a polynomial of degree $n$ with $k$ variables ? Is there some sort of extension to the above result ?

Comment: $$xy-1$$ has infinitely many real roots.

Comment: Ok, but in the case where the number of roots is finite ?